# lsetfilecon failed: Operation not supported on transport endpoint

Tags: android, c++, c, recovery

I have been trying to apply and Android 8 OTA update to a device running Android 6, and during the OTA update I am also trying to set the SELinux security contexts. My Android 6 build does not have any SELinux policies in place.

If I apply an Android 8 full update (USB) to the device, SELinux policy is set correctly.
IF I apply an Android 8 immigration update (USB) over A6, SELinux policy is set correctly.

If I apply an Android 8 OTA over A6, I get the following error.

So here is the raw error output from the 'recovery' log.

```
   :::
Extracted file "/system/vendor/lib/lib_H263_dec_v2_arm11_elinux.so"

Extracted 1678 file(s)
created [/system/priv-app/DefaultContainerService/lib]
created [/system/priv-app/DefaultContainerService/lib/arm]
created [/system/app/LatinIME/lib]
created [/system/app/LatinIME/lib/arm]
ApplyParsedPerms: lsetfilecon of /system/lost+found to u:object_r:system_file:s0 failed: Operation not supported on transport endpoint

ApplyParsedPerms: lsetfilecon of /system/lost+found to u:object_r:system_file:s0 failed: Operation not supported on transport endpointscript aborted: set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed
set_metadata_recursive: some changes failedE:unknown command [log]
E:unknown command [log]
E:Error in /ota/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
I:Saving locale "en_US"
Rebooting...
/ # SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
reboot: Restarting system
```

My current understanding is that the USB updates use the recovery image that is delivered with the package. But for an OTA update, the Android 6 'recovery' is used and hence the above happens. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

So, I have a few questions about the above error:

- why is **lsetfileconfig** failing? (documentation here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lsetfilecon.3.html)
- The **updater-script** in Android 6 mirrors Android 8. And Android 8 also uses **lsetfileconfig** in **ApplyParsedPerms**, what am I missing besides that the 'recovery' images are different?
- Can I save this situation, or do I have to replace the Android 6 'recovery' with Android 8's at the beginning of the OTA update?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I will answer my own question.

I did not get far solving the problem, but from what I could put together an Android OTA update relies on the 'recovery' image on the device itself. In my case the recovery image was from Android 6, and I was trying to apply an Android 8 update on top of it. This led to some incompatibilities (that I still cannot explain) while updating the **/system** partition with SELinux labels.

The workaround I came up with was to use a two-step update process. This is not an original idea, and code was already available from google (which I modified for our purpose). But with the two-step OTA, I updated the **/boot** & **/recovery** partitions first and then reboot back into recovery. The OTA starts over again, but this time it is now using the Android 8 recovery image, and completes by updating the **/system** partition. The device is now successfully upgraded to Android 8.